# onclick event alert value of variable php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to alert id when user click on the button.But i am getting the same id on every button whereas when i inspect element it have different values. This is a part of my code

Fetching code:

```
$sql="select * from `table_name`";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="block" onclick="blockit(this.value);" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Block</button>
```

Query:

```
<script>
function blockit()
{
var a=document.getElementById("block").value;
alert(a);
}
</script>
```

Comment: and your question is? also: you should note that the `blockit`-function you provided does not take any arguments...

Comment: @FranzGleichmann The question is i want to alert value that is related to that button. like if 1st result have value 1 thn it should alert 1 so on

Comment: And different `button`s with same `id`

Comment: what are you doing dude? if you are making function call like `blockit(this.value)` then use `blockit(value)` and `alert(value)`... simple

Comment: use `class` instead of `id` as you may have many buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the parameter to your custom function

```
function blockit(val)
{
  alert(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your every `button` you id is same. from line,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="block" onclick="blockit(this.value);" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Block</button>
```

Do remember, `id` should be unique. Since your `id` is same for all, it always consider only one, and it will neglect others. And hence you are getting same value.

Try with below code,

```
$sql="select * from `table_name`";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="blockit(this.value);" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Block</button>
```

JS,

```
<script>
    function blockit(value){
       alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#block").click(function(){
     var a=$(this).val();
     alert(a);
  });
});
```

Comment: See how may `button`s with same `id` as `block`

Comment: please change set class and use class in click event

Answer (score 0):

Just change your BUTTON code as below,

```
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
      $ID= $row['id'];

  <button type="button" value="<?php echo $ID;?>" onclick="alert('<?php echo $ID;?>')" class="btn btn-danger" id="block" > Block</button>
```

You don't need to use `blockit()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_block" onclick="blockit(this.value);" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Block</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn_block").click(function(){
  var a=$(this).val();
  alert(a);
});
});
```

try this